# Where is the error with this query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have attacked this from many different ways today, I have no figured out the best way to display my data is with a single query that can be displayed in one table.  The problem is I have three queries I am trying to combine, and it is not going very well. I feel like its close but clearly not correct.

```
$sql =  (SELECT SUM(datamb) AS value_sum FROM maindata GROUP BY phonenumber UNION select dataplan as currentplan from   maindata 

GROUP BY phonenumber UNION SELECT DISTINCT phonenumber AS value_sum1 FROM maindata);


$result = mysql_query($sql);



if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo "<TABLE id='display'>";
echo "<td><b>Data Usage This Period: ". ROUND ($row["value_sum"],2) . "MB</b></td> ";
echo "<td><b>Data Plan: ". $row["currentplan"] . "</b></td> "; 
echo "<td><b>Phone Number: ". $row["value_sum1"] . "</b></td> ";  
echo "</TABLE>"; 

}
```

The Problem is I want three columns of data and I get just one column with all data

Comment: So what exactly is the question/problem?

Comment: You're using UNION. I'm fairly sure you want to JOIN the tables instead, but since you've not said what the problem is, that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

First replace this line :

```
$sql =  (SELECT SUM(datamb) AS value_sum FROM maindata GROUP BY phonenumber UNION select dataplan as currentplan from   maindata GROUP BY phonenumber UNION SELECT DISTINCT phonenumber AS value_sum1 FROM maindata);
```

By

```
$sql =  "(SELECT SUM(datamb) AS value_sum FROM maindata GROUP BY phonenumber UNION select dataplan as currentplan from   maindata GROUP BY phonenumber UNION SELECT DISTINCT phonenumber AS value_sum1 FROM maindata);"
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` adds extra rows to the query. It looks like you just want multiple columns. See if this query gets you any closer; if not please show some sample data and expected results:

```
SELECT
  phonenumber AS value_sum1
  dataplan AS currentplan,
  SUM(datamb) AS value_sum
FROM maindata
GROUP BY
  phonenumber,
  dataplan
```

Also, consider *not* aliasing the `phonenumber` and `dataplan` columns - the aliases in this case just confuse things. You'll need to change the index values in the PHP code accordingly.